# How to Unblank lock screen

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have connected a monitor to my laptop. After locking, the screen goes blank after 10 seconds which makes the monitor looks empty. So I wanted to keep the lock screen alive so that it can show the time and the wallpaper in the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to keep the lock screen alive to show off my cool wallpaper in my work system.

All you have to do is simply add this [Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/) and customize it according to your requirements.

[image: gnome-extension-screenshot]